# Install Anaconda on Ubuntu with preexisting Python

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, ubuntu-16.04

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Python 2.7 and 3.5. I've set up virtual environments to access both 2.7 and 3.5 separately and everything works fine.

Now, I need to install Anaconda to access some libraries for a class I am taking. Whats the best way to do this without disrupting the virtual environments I have already set up.

Comment: Anaconda is a *Python distribution* that comes with its own Python interpreter.

Comment: Hence the question: Will the anaconda python distribution create conflicts with the preexisting native python?

Comment: In what way? It's two completely separate programs. Generally, as long as you aren't doing anything funky with your PATH, then they should coexist peacefully. Especially if you use `conda` environments.

Answer (score 1):

Install Miniconda, a mini version of Anaconda that includes just conda, its dependencies and Python.

https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html#installing-conda-on-a-system-that-has-other-python-installations-or-packages

You do not need to uninstall other Python installations or packages in order to use conda. Even if you already have a system Python, another Python installation from a source such as the macOS Homebrew package manager and globally installed packages from pip such as pandas and NumPy, you do not need to uninstall, remove, or change any of them before using conda.

Answer (score 0):

**Try using documentation of anaconda as most of the dependencies are untouched while installing it**